# Prisma include results (select related) compatible with typescript?

Tags: typescript, prisma

I have a prisma query with an `include` that does a join with another model:

```
await prisma.song.findMany({
    include: {
      artist: true
    }
})
```

Prisma will add the artist under `song.artist`, but `.artist` isn't in the interface for `song`, Prisma's schema includes only the direct fields for that. Typescript then errors with:

`Property 'artist' does not exist on type {type definition for song}`

Is there a way to generate prisma types with expanded definitions for possible foreign key relations, so that Typescript will allow this access?

Comment: What's your Prisma schema for the two tables look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, found the prisma supported answer in this doc: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/advanced-type-safety/operating-against-partial-structures-of-model-types#problem-using-variations-of-the-generated-model-type

In my case, the working solution:

```
import { Prisma } from '@prisma/client'

const albumWithIncludes = Prisma.validator<Prisma.albumDefaultArgs>()({
    include: { 
        artist: true
    },
  })

export type AlbumWithIncludes = Prisma.albumGetPayload<typeof albumWithIncludes>
```

and then assigning `AlbumWithIncludes` as the return type of my query

Comment: one thing I'm not sure of is whether the `include` clause can be re-used between this type definition and the original query